# how to add state wise tax charge without adding customer and product class

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, php-5.4

my question is bit technical. i want to ask if i belong to state named NJ, and i want apply tax rule only on this state, means if user selects NJ on checkout as its billing state it should charge him 7% extra in checkout. i have made the tax rule as well but unable to implement on front end.
i want this without influence of product and customer class.
if i am wrong please give me proper direction with step by step guide.
i am using magento 1.8.0.
please help........................

Comment: my simple purpose is only that if as user i choose NJ as my state in checkout it adds 7% tax and just add it in final net amount as well. for all other it act like normal order but for NJ it should show and adds as well....simply this thing please.....

Comment: please any magento geek??????????????

Comment: for the sake of god give me direction  - i am badly stuck at this point and my project is not going to end..

Comment: Closing pending further explanation of "i have made the tax rule as well but unable to implement on front end."